# Where is defined MVC 4 WebApi custom errors when deployed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-web-api

Here is the thing, when I deploy the SAME PACKAGE (copy and paste) with the same Web.config to my local IIS and to the production server IIS i get two different responses when occur errors in the application.

in my local IIS:

```
{
"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"The method or operation is not implemented.",
"ExceptionType":"System.NotImplementedException",
"StackTrace":" at AppCenter.Web.Controllers.ApplicantsController.d__a.MoveNext() in e:\\Sample.Web\\Controllers\\HomeController.cs:line 86"
}
```

in the prod server IIS:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

I would like to know where is the configuration that makes it happen, for example, i would like the server to show the stack trace. The Web.config (where I though would be the place for that) is the same in both, so I think that it is somewhere else. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` on `HttpConfiguration` controls this information. As you can imagine, the behavior which you are noticing is deliberate so as to not expose too much information which probably could cause a security issue. If you would want a the config file to drive this setting, you could read it yourself and set this policy when webapi configuration is being setup.

Comment: first of all, thank u, that is what I was looking for, but, the thing is, how it knows that my local IIS is different from the server IIS?